# Topshelf and NLog - Using Custom Variables

Tags: nlog, topshelf

How can I use [custom variables and layout](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Event-Context-Layout-Renderer) in a Topshelf application that uses the **UseNLog()** implementation? I would want to send something like an ID number so that it can be put into the logs using the **${mdc:item=MyValue}** syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext** of NLog like so:

```
NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set("PropertyName", PropertyValue);
```

The first argument of the Set is a string indicating the property name. The second argument takes an object as its value.

Comment: of course you need to read them with `${mdc:MyValue}` instead of ` ${event-properties}`. See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/MDC-Layout-Renderer